# UWP Camera preview: "No suitable transform was found to encode or decode"

Tags: encoding, camera, uwp, preview

I'm previewing a camera with a CaptureElement in UWP. But why do i get the error: "No suitable transform was found to encode or decode" when using certain resolutions? It happens when using a webcam

I don't get the error when i use this method: mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(...). but if i use this method, the captureelement doesn't get scaled to the resolution i want (capture element has it's strech attribute set to none because i don't want quality loss)

```
        try
        {
            MediaCaptureInitializationSettings mediacapturesettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = DeviceInfo.Id };
            await mediacapture.InitializeAsync(mediacapturesettings);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog(exception.Message);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }


        captureelement.Source = mediacapture;
        captureelement.FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

        await mediacapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        // await mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, Resolution.EncodingProperties);
        await mediacapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, Resolution.EncodingProperties,null);

        VideoRotation currentrotation = Rotation;
        mediacapture.SetPreviewRotation(currentrotation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't get the error when i use this method: mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(...). but if i use this method, the captureelement doesn't get scaled to the resolution i want .
>
> It only happens the first time i callstartpreview().

I've consulted internally and got a response. This problem is probably graphic driver related. Your graphic driver may require your camera device preview to be in running state before you call `MediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync`, so you got this error and only got it at the first time.

> i want to know the difference between the two methods.

Difference:

1. [MediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.setencodingpropertiesasync.aspx) set the property on the camera sink. You can set resolutions and rotation here that the camera does not support and then an encoder will do work to convert to desired format.
2. [MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700895.aspx) set the properties on the source. You can only set the configurations that the camera supports.

So the size of preview window is controlled by the Xaml `CaptureElement`. If you are using `VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync` and want to resize the preview window, you can only set the `Stretch="UniformToFill"` to let the preview window fill the parent element.

Comment: I already do this. My resolution property returns the resolution picked from a combobox that contains all resolutions returned by getavailablemediastreamproperties

Comment: OK, it's weird. Could you please try the Scenario 1 of official sample in my answer. Try different resolutions see if all can run correctly. If there is no error by the official sample maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem, I'll test it on my machine and check what went wrong.

Comment: the problem is that in the samples, the same thing happens with the SetEncodingPropertiesAsync() method, that's why i want to know the difference between the two methods.Only when using SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(), the quality is perfect. The camera app on windows 10 uses this method i think, because there's no quality loss

Comment: The difference is not documented. I guess `SetEncodingPropertiesAsync` and `VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync` are doing the same thing under different scenarios. Please see  remarks of [VideoDeviceController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Another weird thing happens: after i take a pic and go back to the preview, the quality is great...

Comment: Could you please try another sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit). Check if you can run this correctly.

Comment: same result, i tested all the samples.

Comment: it only happens the first time i callstartpreview(). i think it has something to do with layoutpasses.
this works but it's still pixelated the first time:
captureelement.Width = Resolution.Width;
captureelement.Height = Resolution.Height;
captureelement.Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.Fill;

Comment: I've consulted internally and got a response. I have changed my answer, please have a check.

Comment: Thanks alot for the info! I wish i could return the favor somehow. This probably explains my "no suitable tranformation method found" error when i pick a rgb24 format while using the setencodingpropertiesasync method: i guess i don't have a codec for it. If you have any hacks or ideas on how to get the capture element in running state to show the correct resolution initially, let me know.